# How to make customAdapter fill gridview height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am working on Sudoku app. The layout is 9x9 GridView. Each GridView include 9 Textviews by customAdapter. I want to make the 9 TextViews to fill the height of each GridView. How?

This is what I am having now [image]

Here is myGridAdapter:

```
public class myGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] mobileValues;

public myGridAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] arrayEmpty) {
    this.context = mainActivity;
    this.mobileValues = arrayEmpty;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from text_item.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_item, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}
.....
}
```

This is the XML for each text item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
    android:text="@string/_1"
    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the shape for each TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#777777" />
</shape>
```

I want my Gridview to be like this one [image]

After applying the first answer of bakriOnFire

[image]

Comment: what is the LayoutParams of your GridView..hav u set its width and height to match_parent?

Comment: @bakriOnFire I don`t edit LayoutParams programmatically, I only rely on the Params in the XML file

Comment: yes..hav u set its width and height to match_parent of GridView in xml..

Comment: Which XML fiel exaclty and which Item you want me to modify its height and width ? @bakriOnFire

Comment: @bakriOnFire The Gridview already Fill the parent because its background color (Dark grey) is stretching to the end as you can see. The light grey is the background color for the outter layout

Comment: use a tablelayout. gridview is not for this kind of display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the height of each LinearLayout of TextView that you inflate in your GridView's adapter to screenHeight/3.

In getView after inflating the textView's xml, cast the inflated view to LinearLayout and set its height as:

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.menu_items, null);

int screenHeight = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

ll.setMinimumHeight(screenHeight/3);
```

**Edit**

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

text_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] str = { "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" ,
             "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        gridView.setAdapter(new myGridAdapter(this, str));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

            }

        });

    }

    public class myGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private String[] mobileValues;

        public myGridAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] arrayEmpty) {
            this.context = mainActivity;
            this.mobileValues = arrayEmpty;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            LinearLayout gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                // get layout from text_item.xml
                gridView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_item, null);

                int screenHeight = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

                gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, screenHeight/9));


                //gridView.setMinimumHeight(screenHeight/9);
                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(mobileValues[position]); 

            } else {
                gridView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mobileValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

In the getView what i've done is i've inflated the text_item.xml for 9x9 times, in which i've dynamically set the layout height of text_item to screenHeight/9.
Let me know if it work for you or not.

**Edit 2**

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="9"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

text_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"

    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please, modify your code to my example. I cant understand it well

Comment: Note that I have 9 Gridviews in the MainLayout, so I think I can`t use ScreenHight directly

Comment: Can I do this: int screenHeight =  gridView.getHeight()/3;

Comment: you'll get the gridView's height as 0 until it is painted..you can do it all by calculation..give the height of each gridViews as screenHeight/3 and give the height of each cells of each gridview as screenHeight/9.

Comment: An exception, I think this will not work with my layout, I have buttons and Gridviews of Text views ,so getting screen size will not be a good solution. Thank you BTW

Comment: let me see if i can do something with your code..will let u know if i come up with something.

Comment: i was wondering, why do u need 9 GridViews with 3x3 cells. why not having a single grid with 9x9 cells..check my edit..its working..

Comment: That`s a very good idea, but how about highlighting every 9x9 cells? is is possible? This is the main reason that made me try to use 9 Gridviews

Comment: change activity_main.xml and text_item.xml as in my **Edit 2**..you'll get the borders.

Comment: First, Thank you very much for your efforts. Second, Your edits works fine. Third, I am now suffering from the same problem. I want to Stretch the Height of the Cells to fill the Parent. I am now having 9x9 cells but filling only 50% of the screen and the rest is empty. I want it to fill the screen

Comment: We are now at the same initial problem, how to stretch the GridView Items to fill parent?

Comment: I have attached a snapshot of the current layout in your edits. Check it out

Comment: i can't see any attachement...the lines **int screenHeight = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

                gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, screenHeight/9));** will strech the grid cells to fill the screen..i've checked it myself...you r doing something wrong..just chk it..

Comment: I am using your MainActivity and your text_item.xml and your Adapter I think there is nothing more I can do. Can you please send me a screenshot of you layout if it works, or Send to me the project you have created to test this. If you works as a project I will modify on it and Accept you Answer. Thank you

Comment: can u debug an tell me what is the value of dis variable **int screenHeight** in the getView.

Comment: `getHeight()` is deprecated

Comment: I face the exact same problem. Definitely an improvement of my previous situation but still the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can get device height width and for 3 row n col divide by 3 both and set programmtically height width may solve your problem.

Comment: Note that I have 9 Gridviews in the MainLayout, so I think I can`t use ScreenHight directly. Is there is a way to get Gridview height ?

Comment: in getView where u r inflating.u r generating nine view named gridView in ur class.i am talking about xml for each item.as per your code u can do like this gridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:columnWidth="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```

This may help u

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the problem still exist. This code only made the spacing bigger but the Cell size still the same

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this open source sample for soduku.

http://code.google.com/p/opensudoku-android/

This will help you  to draw 9 X9 grdiview.

Hi this code.

```
<TextView   
        android:id="@+id/num"       
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"        
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="25sp"     
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </TextView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think I am looking for just one line of code that make the TextViews fill the height of the GridView. If you can help me with this I would be grateful for that.

Comment: hi have a look at this idea. http://code.google.com/p/starsudoku/source/browse/trunk/StarSudoku/res/layout/game.xml?r=8

Answer (score 1):

Since GridView will function when your adapter is called and does not have a height property for each cell/child, your best option may be to create an image of the w/h that you want and set it as textView.SetBackGround...

This is what I used for my Sudoku app. It is on play store, please check out the screen and let me know your thoughts.

At the PlayStore - EasySudoku, free download - http://tinyurl.com/c4qra79

Comment: That is the functionality, but what about the interface? I wanted to separate each Square of 9 Textviews to look better to the user