# Custom GridView's Last row items not showing fully

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview, android-gridview

In My application I have to show all `List Items` in `GridView` and then while scroll down the `GridView` it needed to scroll the upper View(top of GridView) also along with Grid.For this purpose I have used **HeaderGridView** [Add a Header to a GridView (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217386/add-a-header-to-a-gridview-android/24617051#24617051). What I needed is working fine but the GridView's last row items are not viewing fully as like attached image.So,anyone please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default property of the gridview. It will show as like that only. If you need it in your own way, then you can solve it only by **customizing the gridview** by displaying the items in the gridview according to the **screen height**. This is only just a hint to solve your problem. So Please check this and if you doesn't got solution, please let me know.

[Android gridview adjusting to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697681/android-gridview-adjusting-to-screen-size)

[android How to stretch rows in the gridview to fill screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067449/android-how-to-stretch-rows-in-the-gridview-to-fill-screen)

[How to make customAdapter fill gridview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398318/how-to-make-customadapter-fill-gridview-height)

I think this links may give you some guidelines.