# GridView is not showing last row

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I have the following GridView:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

and the following Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/planlayout_teams_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Tambora 0 - 0 Balagath"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/planlayout_status_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="noch unentschieden"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/planlayout_menu_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text=".\n.\n."
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And everything is working fine except for the last item(s). Whether there is one or two items left, the whole row is not displayed. I googled a lot but nothing could help me.

Edit: I have the same "problem" as here: [Custom GridView's Last row items not showing fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939488/custom-gridviews-last-row-items-not-showing-fully) but those links don't help me.

Comment: You are adding this item programmatically to the grid or what?

Comment: Yes, with an Adapter.

Comment: @TatianaGerth try changing your height to fill_parent of gridview

Comment: still the same and fill_parent is deprecated anyway

Comment: I tried the same with RecyclerView and there it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about your layout. Your adapter load your all items but your layout not let you see last item because of your top margin.
You can edit your grid layout like this. Can you try this way.

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this also doesn't work. But the difference between this and my solution is that this solution gives the feeling that I'm at the end when I scroll down, there is this animation like at the start when you want to scroll up more. In my solution there was no animation. And I also tried without the top margin and the problem was still there.

Answer (score 0):

just try this -->

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/mGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:columnWidth="172dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"/>
```

**Or try with custom gridview**

your gridview code on layout something like this :--

```
     <com.yourpackagename.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/mGridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="-2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="-10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        />
```

MyGridview activity:-

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView {
public MyGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightSpec;

    if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {

        heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    }
    else {
        heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
}
 }
```

In your mainactivity (activity where you want to declare the gridview)

```
    private MyGridView mGridView;
    //also add your adapter of gridview
    .
    .
    oncreate(){
     mGridView = getView().findViewById(R.id.mGridView);
     //then attach your adapter
      

    adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext()...whatever parameters you have in your constructor);
    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

try this custom gridview...still it doesnt worked let me know

Comment: Thanks, but it also didn't help.

Comment: @TatianaGerth see my latest edit ..still it doesnt worked let me know